# How to use Get method in dart?

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, postman

How to use Get method in dart and then decode the json (which come back from server) to a variable?
Any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http & convert package to get it done easily :
[htttp](https://pub.dev/packages/http) [convert](https://pub.dev/packages/convert)

```
 import 'dart:convert' as convert;
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
 var url =
      Uri.https('your url', 'apiEndPoint', {'queryParameter': '{queryValue}'});

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
  var response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse =
        convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    var item = jsonResponse['itemName'];
    print('Item is : $item.');
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }
```